# Multiple versions include of a chapter

Tags: cross-referencing, include

I would like to include a chapter two times, a short version in the main part and a long version in the appendix. Everything works fine except the labels and references. Is there a way to redefine labels in a local context? I could us a \IFDEFINE statement around every label or ref but that is not very convenient.

Any suggestions welcome, Thx!!

```
==================== main.tex =================
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\begin{document}
\include{kapitel}
\begin{appendix}
\newcommand*{\LONGVERSION}{}
\include{kapitel}
\end{appendix}
\end{document}

==================== kapitel.tex =================
\chapter{This is a chapter}\label{chap:mychapter}
This is a test with a reference to my chapter \ref{chap:mychapter}
\ifdefined\LONGVERSION
\section{Variant LONG}
This is a long version of the chapter, which contains a lot of 
additional information. This shall be placed in the appendix.
\else
\section{Variant SHORT}
This is the short version.
\fi
```

Comment: Crosspost to [goLaTeX](http://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=70286#70286) and [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/12325/kapitel-mehrfach-einbinden).

Comment: Great solution, thanks for your expertise. However the soution adresses two different topics. 1.) replacing my construction "\ifdefined" with "\iftoggle" (nice but not strictly necessary) 2.) Main point is using input instead of include in one instance and the self defined prefix addon. GREAT HELP!!

Comment: @MW2015: So what does my solution mean? Is it good,is it bad? It was a quick solution, due to lack of time

Comment: @MW2015: Es ist nicht ok, wenn eine Lösung hier angeboten und dann einfach in einem anderen Forum übernommen wird. Böses Foul ;-)

Comment: No offense intended. Added references. THX!!

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: your solution is very fine, however solved more problems then asked for. For beginners it might not be obvious, that only the definition of the \labelprefix and using \input instead of \include at one point does the trick.

Comment: @MW2015: Use a clearer post next time please... and it was not clear that `\include` is not mandatory at all (I am not a fan of `\include` anyway`)

Comment: in my case \include is needed, as I use the chapterbib environment, which requires such to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use a `\labelprefix` which is changed according to the toggle switch `longversion` (I used `etoolbox` macros for this) and a predefined `\shortlabelprefix` and `\longlabelprefix`.

However, this does not work, if the short version of the chapter is input via `\include` twice, since each input overwrites the old label values.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\newcommand\shortlabelprefix{short}%
\newcommand\longlabelprefix{long}%
\newcommand\labelprefix{\shortlabelprefix}%


\newtoggle{longversion}
\togglefalse{longversion}

\begin{document}
\input{kapitel}


\begin{appendix}
\renewcommand{\labelprefix}{\longlabelprefix}
\toggletrue{longversion}
\include{kapitel}
\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

**kapitel.tex**

```
\chapter{This is a chapter}\label{\labelprefix::chap:mychapter}
This is a test with a reference to my chapter \ref{\labelprefix::chap:mychapter}
\iftoggle{longversion}{%
\section{Variant LONG}
This is a long version of the chapter, which contains a lot of 
additional information. This shall be placed in the appendix.
}{%
\section{Variant SHORT}
This is the short version.
}
```

**short variant**

[image]
**long variant**

[image]

Comment: There is a comment to the question, i think it is addressed to you?

Comment: definitely not me.

Comment: @Johannes_B: ??? Definitely not you?

Comment: Definitely not addresssed to me.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, and my solution is obviously not correct ;-)

Comment: Look at the german sites, obviously it was helpful.

Comment: Now you also got an upvote ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B: The upvote is not the point... the behaviour of the OP is vile

Comment: @Johannes_B: Left a comment on TeXWelt

Comment: Seen it, welcome there :-) Feel free to tackle the unnanswered list